# Why does $("input").first() not work on Google Forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, google-forms

I was using [this Google form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1MuRN3iOw3zR28RxPrEZfYKGDNiZMTtnOewknASdTxt0/viewform?hl=en&formkey=dDliTk5XU1R4RUMtb2c1WDZxWHNENmc6MQ&fbzx=3205651701266619319#gid=0) for Selenium practice, and realized that I couldn't select the first input field with $("input").first()

I verified this with the web browser (Firefox) console tools. When I would try to select the input field from there, I would receive the console message:

```
$("input").first()
TypeError: $(...).first is not a function
```

I know I can select the field using it's id, class, etc, but I'm just confused as to why .first() doesn't work.

Comment: What does `$("input")` return ?

Comment: This is because only a `formviewer.js` is being loaded on the page, not jQuery. The `.first()` function is jQuery's and so doesn't exist on Google Forms.

Comment: @Rayon $("input") returns all input fields, such as text boxes.

Comment: @kittenchops, Are you sure it is `jQuery-wrapped` object ?

Comment: @SébastienVercammen How can you tell that Jquery is not being used on the page?

Comment: @kittenchops By viewing the source code, I noticed there was no jQuery file being included. To double-check, I entered $ in console which returned `function $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }`. jQuery has the signature `function (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't that `.first` doesn't work but rather `$()` isn't returning what you think it should return.  The firefox console has a function called `$`  which is NOT the same as `jQuery` despite the name.

More details are available here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/The_command_line_interpreter

Comment: Even webkit console has `$`